# Is a view in the database updatable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

Can you update a view in a database?
If so, how?
If not, why not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The actual answer is "it depends", there are no absolutes.

The basic criteria is it has to be an updateable view *in the opinion of the database engine*, that is to say can the engine uniquely identify the row(s) to be updated and secondly are the fields updateable. If your view has a calculated field or represents the product of a parent/child join then the default answer is probably no.

However its also possible to cheat... in MS SQL Server and Oracle (to take just two examples) you can have triggers that fire when you attempt to insert or update a view such that you can make something that the server doesn't think updateable into something that is - usually because you have knowledge that the server can't easily infer from the schema.

Comment: "It depends" - the database professional's favorite answer.  8-)

Comment: Too many years of being a "programmer" with too many conversations with clients/users where nice answers that can be represented by zeros and ones are few and far between (-:

Comment: In Oracle, too, you can create `INSTEAD OF` triggers that will handle inserts, updates and deletes on a view.

Comment: @Jeffrey - added reference to oracle as well as MS SQL to show that its not just one db that has the appropriate triggers (been most of a decade since I did any Oracle work). I won't add more - hopefully its obvious that the list is not exclusive!

Comment: You can update but with conditions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is "it depends". You can't update an aggregate column in a view for example. For Oracle views you can Google for "updatable join view" for some examples of when you can and cannot update a view.

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL has RULEs to create updatable VIEWs. Check [the examples in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-update.html#AEN48719) to see how to use them.

Ps. In PostgreSQL a VIEW is a RULE, a select rule.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are updatable but not always. Views can be updated under followings:

- If the view consists of the primary key of the table based on which the view has been created.
- If the view is defined based on one and only one table.
- If the view has not been defined using groups and aggregate functions.
- If the view does not have any distinct clause in its definition.
- If the view that is supposed to be updated is based on another view, the later should be updatable.
- If the definition of the view does not have any sub queries.

Answer (score 3):

In the past it wasn't possible to update any views. The main purpose of a view is to *look* at data, hence the name. It could also have been called a *stored query*.

Today, many database engines support to update views. It's bound to restrictions, some updates are virtually impossible (eg. calculated columns, group by etc).

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches:

1. INSTEAD OF trigger, which basically shifts the problem to the user. You write some procedural code that does the job. Certainly, no guarantees is made about correctness, consistency, etc. From RDBMS engine perspective a trigger that deletes everything from the base tables, no matter what update is made in the view, is perfectly fine.
2. Much more ambitious is view updates handled exclusively by RDBMS engine. Not much progress is made here: to put it mildly, if you have some good ideas there, then you can roll out PhD thesis. In practice, your favorite RDBMS might allow some limiting ad-hock view updates; check the manual:-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are - the syntax is the same as updating a table

```
Update MyView
Set Col1 = "Testing"
Where Col2 = 3
Go
```

There a few conditions to creating an View that can be updated.  They can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

**EDIT:**

I must add that is based on MS SQL

Comment: Why `go`? I don't think it's a valid sql construct except for SSMS. :)

Comment: @Denis - Thanks! I have just realised that the OP has tagged question Oracle & PostgreSQL. Oops

Comment: I believe your query will work in other systems as well sans the go part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but have a look at [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) and see the section **Updatable Views**

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

See Remarks\updateable view

Answer (score 1):

When a view is created in SQL Server, metadata for the referenced table columns (column name and ordinal position) is persisted in the database. Any change to the referenced base table(s) (column re-ordering, new column addition, etc) will not be reflected in the view until the view is either:

•Altered with an ALTER VIEW statement 
•Recreated with DROP VIEW/CREATE VIEW statements 
•Refreshed using system stored procedure sp_refreshview

Comment: This answer seems to be copied directly from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1427/table-changes-not-automatically-reflected-in-a-sql-server-view/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using an [INSTEAD OF](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i10900) trigger.

Answer (score 0):

We generally don't update a view. A view is written to fetch data from the various tables based on joins and where conditions put.

View is just a logic put in place which gives the desired data set on invoking it.

But not sure on what scenario one needs to update a view.